# python: cumulative density plot

Tags: python, cumulative-sum

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = 
   Time_to_event  event
0         0 days    443
1         1 days    226
2         2 days    162
3         3 days     72
4         4 days     55
5         5 days     30
6         6 days     36
7         7 days     18
8         8 days     15
9         9 days     14
10       10 days     21
11       11 days     13
12       12 days     10
13       13 days     10
14       14 days      8
```

I want to produce a cumulative density plot of the sum of the events per days. For example 0 days 443, 1 days = 443 + 226 etc.

I am currently trying this code:

```
    stat = "count"  # or proportion
    sns.histplot(df, stat=stat, cumulative=True, alpha=.4)
```

but I come up with a pretty terrible plot:
[image]

If I could also come up with a line instead of bars that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a *combo* of [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) :

```
df["cumsum"] = df["event"].cumsum()

plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
sns.lineplot(x="Time_to_event", y="cumsum", data=df);
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for your plot values is:

```
xvalues=df["Time_to_event"]
yvalues=df["event"].cumsum()
```

The code could look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv("test.txt")
print(df.columns)
print(df)

plt.bar(df["Time_to_event"],df["event"].cumsum()) 
# replace plt.bar with plt.plot for a plotted diagram
plt.show()
```